# International app; multilingual website or English only? SEO

Tags: seo, multilingual

I own the application that can run for every fitness business in the world, so I would love to compete with existing applications that are served.

The website consist of lading pages that offers products, docs, blog articles etc.
Also, app name is unique so I have purchased long time ago several top-level domains, so I have `http://my-app.com`, `http://my-app.de` `http://my-app.fr`, `http://my-app.pl`.

I know that the perfect situation would be to have each website, blog article, doc article translated into particular language, however it's very hard to maintain - money-wise and time-wise.

But what if I do kind of landing pages only, e.g.

`http://my-app.fr` homepage will be handled in French but links to docs and blog will remain English? Is this okay? Does it help?

Or should I go English only and promote my website using some ad campaigns?
Once I've read that Google does not care about what language is on the website but if the context fits to the searched query.

What is the best way to handle it? How can I be found if someone will type in his local google a phrase in his own language things that would match my context in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommend to host all multilingual content on the same (.com) domain, inside of language folders, .com/fr like this. You provide your main domain much more content weight, as you would divide the content into language parts and host them on different domains.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. You are right, it will be better to build up a rank for one domain instead of several ones.